# How to find all files with a specific extension list

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have the following `find` command which will give me all files:

```
find /Users/david/Desktop/-type f
```

How would I find only those files with extension `txt` `mpg` or `jpg` ?

Comment: You need  a space before `-type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-o` in the `find` filter to combine different criteria with "OR". You need to wrap them in parentheses because they have lower precedence than the default "AND" combination of criteria.

```
find /Users/david/Desktop -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.mpg' -o -name '*.jpg' \)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Use `-iname` instead of `-name`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ABSURD and very low level bash way to do this:

copy and paste:

```
mkfifo /tmp/grep1
mkfifo /tmp/grep2
grep -i "dmg" /tmp/grep1 & export GREP1=$!
grep -i "zip" /tmp/grep2 & export GREP2=$!
find ./ -type f | tee /tmp/grep1 /tmp/grep2 >/dev/null
echo $GREP1
echo $GREP2
kill $GREP1
kill $GREP2
rm -f /tmp/finder
ps -a | grep -i grep
```

I suffered to prove it was feasible.

Example Output:

```
bash-3.2$ mkfifo /tmp/grep1 ; mkfifo /tmp/grep2 ; grep -i "dmg" /tmp/grep1 & export GREP1=$! ; grep -i "zip" /tmp/grep2 & export GREP2=$! ; find ./ -type f | tee /tmp/grep1 /tmp/grep2 >/dev/null ; echo $GREP1; echo $GREP2 ; kill $GREP1 ; kill $GREP2 ; rm -f /tmp/finder ; ps -a | grep -i grep
mkfifo: /tmp/grep1: File exists
mkfifo: /tmp/grep2: File exists
[6] 82891
[7] 82892
.//iTerm2-2_1_1.zip
.//Cisco_WebEx_Add-On.dmg
.//MacPass-0.5.1-alpha.zip
.//googlechrome-2.dmg
.//googlechrome.dmg
82891
82892
bash: kill: (82891) - No such process
[6]-  Done                    grep -i "dmg" /tmp/grep1
[7]+  Done                    grep -i "zip" /tmp/grep2
82897 ttys012    0:00.00 grep -i grep
```

Comment: That will expand the wildcard `*.mpg` into a list of filenames, so it will execute `grep -i file1.mpg file2.mpg file3.mpg ...`

Comment: How does this answer his question about how to search for multiple extensions?

Comment: in the above, the named pipes aren't cleaned up properly... so... fix that before use.

Comment: Why are you exporting the `GREPn` variables? They're not being used in any subprocesses.

Comment: Why do you need two `grep` commands instead of `grep -E 'dmg|zip'`?

Comment: You don't need to kill the `grep` processes, they'll exit by themselves when they read `EOF` from the named pipes.

Comment: There's nothing sane about this.  I just decided to demo low level bash capabilities.  grep -E doesn't operate well in my environment though, I'll have to look into why.  as for the export, I just did that because again.. nothing sane about this just making it more absurd.

Comment: If you want to write insane code, try codegolf sites or enter obfuscated coding contests. It's not really appropriate for SO.